# Clearing a DateTime list in C#

Tags: c#, list, datetime

I have a list of DateTime's that I am using in a foreach loop and I need to have a clear list at the beginning of every loop

I was wondering if there are any built in methods that I can use to clear it or will I have to nest a for loop in the foreach loop in order to clear the list?

I have tried these two methods but neither of them worked

```
    foreach( DateTime i in listname){ 
         listname.Remove(i); 
    } 

    listname.RemoveAll();
```

Comment: do you want to clear entire list?

Comment: @programtreasures yes I do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `clear` function to clear the list

```
  public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Your code goes here
            List<DateTime> dtList = new List<DateTime>(){
                DateTime.Now
            };

            Console.WriteLine("Before count " + dtList.Count());

            dtList.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("After count " + dtList.Count());
        }
```

here is demo https://dotnetfiddle.net/bHp30A